# How to stop a program from running

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, return

I am trying to create a license plate generator. It creates a random license plate whenever you run it. However if there is no name entered, I need to stop the program from continuing to generate the license plate, almost like pausing it until all the information is entered. I know I need a return function but I am not sure how to use it. Here is the code so far:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NameTextBox.Text))
{
    userAnswer = MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid name for the motorist", "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (userAnswer == DialogResult.No)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    sb.Append(currentTime);
    ActivityrichTextBox.Text = ActivityrichTextBox.Text + sb.ToString();

    sb.Clear();
    sb.Append("**Error** failed to enter a valid name");
    ActivityrichTextBox.Text = ActivityrichTextBox.Text + " " + sb.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;

    sb.Clear();
```

I know it will be somewhere in here to stop if the name isn't entered.

Comment: adding a `YesNo` dialog is really not intuitive here.  Make it just an `OK` box.

Comment: `Progam:` "Please Enter a name."  `User:` "NO!"  =P

Comment: You might want to use this component also:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx

There are a lot of examples using it.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I will give you a pattern, as your question seems to be not very well thought through. Basically I understand you want to validate user input when some sort of action is triggered, let's say, a button is pressed. Usually this would look like this:

```
public void btnButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You did not enter text!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        textBox.Focus();
        return; // <=== This exits the btnButton_Clicked method until the button is clicked again
    }

    // Do stuff here if text *was* entered
}
```

So in your case this would look like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NameTextBox.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid name for the motorist", "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

    sb.Clear();
    sb.Append(currentTime);
    sb.AppendLine(" **Error** failed to enter a valid name");

    ActivityrichTextBox.Text = ActivityrichTextBox.Text + sb.ToString();
    return;
}
```

Please also not the correct use of the `StringBuilder` to create the new line for the activity log.

Comment: +1, very well said.  @OP: I would recommend, that you don't use .Length however.  You should add further validation like making sure it's alpha or alphanumeric (whatever you need), as well as using `textBox.Text.Trim().IsEmpty()`

Comment: @sircapsalot Thanks. Not sure why to not use `Length` for a simple input check, but I changed to `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` as this is what the OP uses as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are doing it in Win Form. If so then you do NOT need to pause the program, you can just use events to handle your requirement. Make a button, attach a click event to it. Once the user clicked the button, check if the name text box is empty, if yes then show an error message and call `return;` if not then continue.